# If I were to delete an app on my computer account, will the app be deleted on the administrator's account?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

So I have this app that keeps bugging my account on a shared computer of mine. I want to delete it, but I'm concerned that it will delete itself on the administrator's account.

Will it delete itself or will it just be deleted on my account?

Comment: If it is an app, probably just your account. If it is an application (i.e. traditional Windows program that you have to uninstall in Control Panel) then probably yes, *all* 
 accounts unless you installed it just for your user account.

Comment: Win32 application or UWP application?

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on the application type.
If it's a Windows Store app, uninstall it only for current user.
If it's a desktop app, it will remove for all users include administrator.